# Continous scrolling div menu animation jumpy

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am attempting to create a "menu" that will constantly scroll.  I have the code working but the scrolling animation is very choppy.  How do I make the menu scrolling smoother? I have used animate() before and never had this issue.

jsFidde: https://jsfiddle.net/pwa0sp75/

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var currentSpeed = parseInt($("#scrollSpeed").val());
            setInterval('scroll()', currentSpeed);
        });

function scroll(){
        var scrollSpeed = parseInt($("#scrollSpeed").val());    
        $("#scrollup .divTableBody").animate({ top: '-=' + $('#scrollup .divTableBody .divTableRow:last').height() }, scrollSpeed, 'linear', function() {
            var offset = $('#scrollup .divTableBody .divTableRow:last').offset().top;
            if (offset <= 1352) {
                $('.divTable').css("top", 0);
                $('#scrollup .divTableBody .divTableRow:last').after($('#scrollup .divTableBody .divTableRow:first').detach());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your animations smoother use [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/), it makes your animation very smooth. All you have to do is replace your code from `.animation({...});` to `.velocity({...});` after downloading the Velocity script file and including it in your page. I have been doing the same, to avoid JQuery's choppy animation.

If you want to smooth scroll, then all you need to do is:

```
 $("#buttonToClick").click(function () {
        $("#toWhichDivtoScroll").velocity("scroll", 1000);
    });
```

> ***Edited Answer***

Check if you had properly added the velocity.js and velocity-ui.js files properly in your page. Make some modifications to the below code and try running:

`var topValue = 0;
    function scroll() {
        var scrollSpeed = parseInt($("#scrollSpeed").val());
        $("#scrollup .divTableBody .divTableRow").velocity({top: topValue}, scrollSpeed, 'linear', function () {
            topValue += 25;
            var offset = $('#scrollup .divTableBody .divTableRow:last').offset().top;
            if(offset <= 1352) {
                $('.divTable').velocity("scroll", 500);
                $('#scrollup .divTableBody .divTableRow:last').after($('#scrollup .divTableBody .divTableRow:first').detach());
            }
        });`

Play changing `top` property and even your `scrollSpeed` and `currentSpeed`, as they are part of the choppiness being caused.

To know how to make your animations smooth with **Velocity**, you can refer this link [Improving Velocity UI Animation](https://css-tricks.com/improving-ui-animation-workflow-velocity-js/)

Comment: I tried that and it is still exhibiting the same behavior in that it jumps line to line instead of smoothly scrolling.